# Div not spanning full width on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, html, width

Thank you for reading this! I am having an issue getting color bars (divs) to reach full width on the iphone. When I look at it on my laptop and pull the window in as narrow as possible and scroll all the way to the right, it is not cut off. When I view it on my iphone, there is always space cut off on the right side of the top gray bar and the white div at the bottom, where the background shows through. I am obviously not very experienced with pc to mobile and I appreciate any help and advice!

Site Link: http://ekdesignportfolio.info/test/index4.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's going on here, but I just looked around at your site for a bit and it looks like the short grey bar has something either to do with your backstretch.js or the computation of your body. On a phone your body is computing at 980px (at least on the one I checked), and then you have a min-width set to 1050px. But your body isn't even spanning 100%, instead it's spanning about 2/3 of the page and your grey bar is calculating it's width with respect to the body, that being minimally 1050p.

You have a lot of min-widths set, which isn't going to be good for mobile unless you change them with media queries at lower widths or something. To be honest, I would use a typical css background instead of that jquery script because it's kind of overkill. Try something like,

```
.background-div {
   background: url(images/background-image.png);
   background-size: cover; (or contain, depending on what you want)
}
```

I hope this helps at least a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for looking it over! I forgot to mention that I wanted the background image to stay in place on scroll, which I don't think will work with a pure CSS background (I could be completely wrong though). I added a mobile stylesheet and made the nav font smaller for it, and that seemed to pretty much solve the problem. The nav is not perfectly centered yet, but at least it is better than it was. I still need to check it on an ipad at some point to see if it works there too, fingers crossed. Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to make the background stay in place too, but it might be a little more complex. Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful enough, mark it correct :).